# Can not run two or multiple android emulator at the same time

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator, emulation

I want to test a server/client socket chat program in android and I wanna run
two emulator **at the same time**, I have been search a lot but i didn't 
get anywhere. I tried command prompt by running "emulator -avd test" two times where test is a
previously-created avd, but only the first emulator appears and the second does not appear but when i check the windows task manager, two instance of "emulator.exe" are running.
it does not work even when i duplicate "android" folder in "programe files (x86)" folder, and run each "AVD manager" separately. in this case with running the second emulator, a warning has been appeared on the command prompt screen:

WARNING: Data partition WARNING: Cache partition already in use. changes will not persist!

please help me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create two separate AVD's (test1 and test2). As far as I know you cannot have two running instances of the same AVD.

Comment: That's correct, but if you need to run the same AVD more than once at the same time, just 'clone' your setup to another AVD and run it

Comment: thank you, but even with two different avd, it does not work!

Comment: I would avoid having two versions of the Android SDK installed on your machine. That's likely to result in many headaches in the future. Glad you were able to get it working though.

Comment: It actually does not work: `AVD ... is already running.
If that is not the case, delete the files at ... and try again.`

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing `AVD cache` and image files from `.android` folder in your user's directory.

Before that stop all emulators, stop processes if running, then delete manually `AVD`, and create a new ones.